# addclass on hover not working

Tags: html, redirect

I want to hover on an element (an imagemap area, actually but I made it a simple div for this example) and create an animation on a different div element. Since they're not child or sibilings I had to use java and addclass but it's not working. It looks like the trigger element is not recognized and if I hover it nothing happens

```
<div class="testHover">
  <p>Hover me to change color</p>
</div>
<div id="timeLine">
  <div id="primaGuerraMondiale">
        <h2>Content</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#primaGuerraMondiale {
background: green;
}
.animated {
color:white;
}
```

javascript

```
$('.testHover').hover(function() {
$('#primaGuerraMondiale').addClass('animated');
}, function() {
$('#primaGuerraMondiale').removeClass('animated');
});
```

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/elisapessa/yzLe803n/

Comment: It works. You forgot to select jquery file.

Comment: Tag `facebook` removed – this has nothing to do with “developing for the Facebook platform”, which is what this tag is for. Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You need jQuery 1.9.1 and above to make it work. The code is right.

Answer (score 0):

In the left hand panel in the jsfiddle, there is a section called "Add Resources". Click this, then add the URL into the field and click the + button. This will add your resource (JS or CSS) to the page. After that you click on run and check it:

[image]